Visual Studio does not find drawable ressources
enter image description he
I have a xamarin android project and i cannot for gods sake add the drawable ressources to the xml i cleaned and rebuild reopened visual studio but it seems to me that this is some kind of annoying visual studio bug.
Help. I am getting insane.
Clean and rebuild
Close and open visual studio again
go through all online ressources

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@HackiHack, "does not find drawable ressources" do you mean it showed some error message like this?
Or you can just build and run the project but can't see the the image?
